# Maven-Dependency for Eclipse Birt 4.3.2

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, birt

Has anyone found a Maven-Repository with Eclipse Birt in Version 4.3.2?

Theres only 4.3.1 and 4.3.1a in public Maven-Repositories.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
     <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The newest version in Maven central is 4.3.1a, just [search it](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.birt.runtime%22%20AND%20a%3A%22org.eclipse.birt.runtime%22). But you can try to download snapshots from Sonatype repository, follow this [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable4.2.php#jump_4) from Birt website.

Comment: the newest version from birt is 4.4.0: [Birt Download](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/)

Comment: Sorry, I meant newest version in Maven central

Comment: Do we have maven dependency for birt 4.4.0 ?